# Semantic ui react modal dialog issue

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react in my application.
It used to work perfect but at some point, it stops to render Modal dialogs in the proper place. The only thing I did install, not sure if it's a cause, is a Node 8.9.4
After installing new node version, my npm "ask" me to upgrade sass-loader.

Now all my dialogs open in the Top-Left corner cut by half.
Any idea?

[image]

It does show dialog in the right place if I disable DISPLAY property from css

[image]

Comment: Appears to be an issue after you update to v0.78.3  . Going to open a new issue in their repo.

Comment: im getting the same issue the modal appears top left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Semantic-UI-CSS new `2.3.0` update.

I tried downgrading to `2.2.12` and it fixed the issue for now.

This issue is addressing it:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/issues/40

Comment: try rolling back both css and react. (to `2.2.12` and `0.78.2`)

Comment: Doesn’t help... maybe it somehow related to node version?

Comment: Make sure to remove all your node modules when downgrading. Then do `yarn cache clean` (if using yarn) and then install all modules again

Comment: Been searching for the answer to the Semantic-Ui-React modal problem for ages. This fixed it. Props

Answer (score 1):

OK. Based on *Morinx* comment (tnx btw), I've managed to get Modal dialogue working properly. 
I downgraded, cleaned cache and reinstall modules few times before the help and it didn't work because I used **^** prefix and it was getting the latest version all the time:
Instead of `^2.2.12` use **`2.2.12`**.

So, this issue has been resolved and now we need to wait until the Library bug will be fixed.